# angularjs multiple validator on model

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to add multiple validation directive on a model but it is not working. Individually they work but together they don't work.

I have 2 directives to an input to validate minimum and maximum value that can be entered in it.

```
<input type="text" min-val="2" max-val="5" ng-model="age" />
```

Here is the [pluker](http://plnkr.co/edit/MoT1nf1i1j6LxGk9Hydq?p=preview) link

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost there.

You passed an anonymous function to $parsers and $formatters array:

```js
modelCtrl.$formatters.push(function(value) {
  validator(value);
});
```

Inside the anonymous function you are making a call to your `validator` function, but you're not returning the result.

To remedy, return the function result as in:

```js
modelCtrl.$formatters.push(function(value) {
  return validator(value);
});

modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function(value) {
  return validator(value);
});
```

To simplify your code you might want to use the function name directly as a variable reference (no need for anonymous function):

```js
modelCtrl.$formatters.push(validator);
modelCtrl.$parsers.push(validator);
```

[PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZwBRoO6OrKL5irVA7kcT?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks! Works perfect! I thought attached plunker has correct code.